# Perl Pattern Matching extracting inside brackets

Tags: perl, pattern-matching, matching, brackets

I really need help with coming up with the pattern matching solution...

If the string is `<6>[   84.982642] Killing the process`

How can I extract them into three separate strings...
I need one for `6, 84.982642`, and `Killing the process`..
I've tried many things but these brackets and blank spaces are really confusing me and I keep getting the error message

```
"WARNING: Use of uninitialized value $bracket in pattern match..."
```

Is there anyway I can somehow write in this way

```
($num_1, $num_2, $name_process) = split(/[\-,. :;!?()[\]{}]+/);
```

Not sure how to extract these..

Help Please?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the input is in `$_`

```
($num_1, $num_2, $name_process) = /^<(\d+)>\[([^\]]+)\]\s+(.*)$/;
```

This assumes the first token in the angle brackets is always a number. For a little more generality use

```
($num_1, $num_2, $name_process) = /^<([^>]+)>\[([^\]]+)\]\s+(.*)$/;
```

Explanation:

`<([^>]+)>` - a left-angle-bracket followed one or more characters that are not a right angle-bracket, followed by a right-angle bracket.

`\[([^\]]+)\]` - a left-bracket followed by one or more characters that are not a right bracket, followed by a right bracket

`\s+(.*)` - one or more spaces, then capture everything starting with the first non-blank after that.

Comment: can you please explain how you were able to get that?

Comment: I added an explanation

Comment: Interestingly, $num_1 wasnt grabbing anything. Everything was starting from $num_2, meaning I needed one more variable to grab the last message.. Not sure why. Thanks!